# What is the Java equivalent of PHP flush()?

Tags: java, php, flush

I'am a big fan of
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Can I do the same thing using Java?

thanks for your help

Comment: are you using jsp, a servlet, some other framework, or?

Comment: the reply would be: "struts" if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the equivalent of PHP in java is jsp+servlets, here are the ways to do it:

- in a servlet, call `response.getOutputStream().flush()`
- in a jsp it's the same, but you have to specify `<%@ page autoFlush="false" %>`

Comment: Do i need to mention the buffer size if I set autoflush to false??? This website mentions that you cannot set the autoflush to false if the value of the buffer size is none...  http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/AutoFlushAttribute.shtml

Comment: I think there's a default buffer size of 8kb.

Comment: but if i set it to false than do i need to mention the buffer size??? and also can you give me small example in a jsp cause i am having problem with flushing the buffer ...I did try but met with a jsp exception

Answer (score 1):

[OutputStream.flush()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html)